# idempotency of resource creation in microsoft azure creating a virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-bicep

I am trying to create som infrastructure on azure.

I have a bicep module that looks like this:

```
param location string
param virtualNetworkName string

resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2019-11-01' = {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and I call it from my main bicep file

```
module createCommonVirtualNetwok 'modules/createVirtualNetwork.bicep' = {
  name: 'createCommonVirtualNetwokModule'
  scope: resourceGroup(commonResourceGroupName)
  dependsOn: [
    createResourceGroupModule_common
  ]
  params:{
    virtualNetworkName: commonVNetName
    location: location
  }
}
```

it works fine and creates the vnet.
I also have another module that adds subnets to this vnet which also works.
and a containerapp is later set up to use said subnet.

so far so good.

but when I run the script again at this point it fails on the Virtual network creation module.
the deployment operation details say:

```
Subnet my-subnet is in use by /subscriptions/<mysubid>/resourceGroups/MC_<some-resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/|providers|Microsoft.Compute|virtualMachineScaleSets|aks-agentpool-<someid>-vmss|virtualMachines|3|networkInterfaces|aks-agentpool-<someid>-vmss/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1 and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet."
```

well, it makes sense in a way - It does not want to delete the subnet until its not used...
but I don't recall asking it to create the v-net.
or maybe the fact that I do not specify any subnets makes it think that I want existing subnets to be removed?

how can I just ensure that this resource exists and create it if it does not exists without having it try to kill its child resources if they already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is expected and is a long debated behaviour of vnets\subnets and a couple of other parent\child resources.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/2786

there is nothing you can do about it really, except for create vnet and subnets in the same arm template\bicep file or use some other tool (pulumi, powershell, terraform, etc) which do individual api calls per resource

Comment: OMG, I can't believe this is going on since 2016...
Can you help me better understand the limitations?
if I create a vnet today, and want to add subnets in the future, I should have no problem as long as I never try to re-create the v-net? 
Are there any future changes that I might want to do to the vnet ?

Comment: if you send a PUT api request to update the vnet with your initial config (as-is on the screen right now) it will default the `subnets` property (which is omitted in your code) to an empty array, thus will try to remove all the subnets from your vnet. you can work around this by creating\updating all the subnets using same template and `subnets` property on the vnet (instead of a separete resource per subnet). this way your code will be truly idempotent. alternatively you can do vnet updates via other sources that take existing state and merge your changes and put the result back